# Does ColdFusion support type hinting?

Tags: coldfusion

In PHP I can do:
$var = (int) $_POST['var'];

Is there a way to explicitly set a ColdFusion variable to an integer or a string?

Comment: That's not a [type hint](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php). That's [type casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) (scroll down a bit, there's no anchor).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Variables are typeless in CF. Although if you want to evaluate a variable as either a number or string, you could do:

```
#Val(<variable>)#
```

and for strings

```
#ToString(<variable>)#
```

Comment: Thanks, that pretty much answered it.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what you want to happen for data that can't be converted, maybe you want cfparam?

```
<cfparam name="form.v" type="numeric"/>
```

That will throw an exception if form.v is not present or is not numeric.

You can also test whether a value is numeric (or any other type):

```
<cfif isNumeric(form.v)>
```

and you can 'convert' a string a numeric value:

```
<cfset v = val(form.v) />
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the good information in the other answers, it's worth mentioning that you can use [`isvalid()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fb9.html) to see if a typeless value matches a bunch of different criteria:

```
isvalid('integer',x);
isvalid('float',x);
isvalid('string',x);
```

...etc. There are also some higher-level ones, like:

```
isvalid('email',x);
isvalid('telephone',x);
```

There are times when you must coerce a typeless value into a "true" type -- for instance, when you want to pass an argument to a Java method with more than one signature. You'd use `javacast()`, like so:

```
x = "01";
myJavaFunc.doSomething( x ); // ambiguous -- could be a string or number
myJavaFunc.doSomething( javacast('int', x ) ); // does something
myJavaFunc.doSomething( javacast('string', x ) ); // does something else
```